# Display selected keyboard layout in Windows 7 task-bar notification area

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, notification-area

In control Panel I selected two keyboard layouts, a standard one and an extended one. They mainly differ in that one uses <kbd>`</kbd> as a dead key for composing accented characters. The other allows simple entry of ` without having to press a space bar afterwards.

Because I have more than one keyboard layout selected, I have a keyboard icon in the task-bar notification area.

[image: keyboard icon in notification area]

I can toggle between the two layouts using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> but I have no visual indication of which is currently selected. Just an unvarying icon of a keyboard.

I recall older versions of Windows (XP?) did have at least show a two character country identifier in the notification area.

I can choose "show the Language Bar" (which appears at top of screen) but would prefer something smaller and less conspicuous.

Is there any way to display the name of the current keyboard layout in the task bar notification area? Or at least a different icon for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Properties** of that particular keyboard layout you get option to select a custom Icon.

In **Text Services and Input Language**, selecting the layout and clicking on the Properties button take you to a preview and there is a button at top named `Change Icon...`.

[image: Showing Result of changing Icon]
[image]

This should solves the icon issue but I'm not aware of any possibility of displaying 
name of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Two character country identifier is shown only for different languages. You can add different language and use second layout with that language, so you will have two languages each with it's own keyboard layout - that would show language code in the tray area instead of keyboard icon.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***Region and Language*** in control center
Then pick **Keyboard and Languages**
In earlier windows pick   "**Change keyboard**" button

This opens the "**Text Services and Input Languages**" window
There are three folders at the top . . .
    one of them is "**Language Bar**"

You should find that you can restore the language bar in your taskbar tray by selecting this option in that "language bar" window.