# How do I specifiy a keyboard layout icon in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I have multiple keyboard layouts. In previous versions of Windows, I could specify a different icon for each layout so I could quickly glance in the system tray and determine which layout was being used. This answer documents that process: [Display selected keyboard layout in Windows 7 task-bar notification area](https://superuser.com/questions/480412/display-selected-keyboard-layout-in-windows-7-task-bar-notification-area)

How do I do this in Windows 8? The properties screen is completely different and I can't find a way to assign an icon to each layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone in being completely confused by how Microsoft has Improved Windows 8 to the point of being almost impossible to use it. If they improve it any more, I'm going to have to move to Linux or Mac.

You can see a text-based icon in the tray to show the language.

From the Languages icon in the control panel open the Advanced Settings,
then find an underlined or differently colored (blue) piece of text saying
Change language bar hot keys. Then find the Language Bar tab.

[image]

The Language Bar tab is the first tab among two "Text Services" properties pages, in them you must check Show additional Language Bar Icons in the taskbar.

For demonstration purposes here I have English-US and Inuktitut (Canadian aboriginal language) activated:

[image]

Comment: It may interest people to know that in some cases Windows 8 appears to completely ignore the selected IME Language. IN fact I can't find any native apps that support Inuktitut as an IME.

Comment: Warren, thank you very much. I spent hours yesterday trying to coax an answer out of Google without success. This is a big help to me.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Hopefully soon Google will point HERE. :-)

Comment: but, this is not keyboard layout, this is input language. Isn't it?

Comment: Keyboard layout and IME are exposed through the same taskbar UI elements. In fact, I am unaware of any way to select Keyboard layouts directly, they exist as an element of a selected IME. So as an end user I would call this "changing keyboard layouts" but it's technically an IME I am selecting.  For example, in India, I might select an IME that uses some phonetic latin-to-hindi approach, or an ACTUAL indic keyboard layout like Inscript.   Most users can't tell the difference between an IME and a Keyboard Layout.

Comment: This no longer works in Windows 10 :(

Comment: I think the UI is slightly rearranged but it's all in the tray area still.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for a solution for a long time, and have come up with my own. If you are still interested in doing what the question you linked to does, here is [my guide](http://youtu.be/6wpF4_Rnu2s):

Step-by-step Instructions:

1. Press `Start`
2. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > CTF`
4. Create new Key called `LayoutIcon`
5. Create new Key with the last four digits of the desired language. Language codes can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh825682.aspx
6. Create a new key for the layout. Possible values for this key can be found in:
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Keyboard Layout > Preload`.
7. Create a new String called `IconFile` with value `C:\Windows\system32\msctf.dll` or any other file that has the icon that you want.
8. Create a new DWORD called `IconIndex` with the decimal value counting left to right by columns starting from `0`.
9. Restart the computer

Comment: but. doesn't work